# Hive Window Rank Function

Tags: window, hive, rank

Can we use a rank function in Hive with something as below? We need to apply rank over a interval of 30 seconds. Can this be done in Hive?

```
select rank() over(partition by unit_id, acct_nbr, pe_id, context
order by base_timestamp
range between interval '30 seconds' preceding and current row)
```

Comment: Yes. Example for "60 sec" is in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600543/hive-query-generating-identifiers-for-a-sequence-of-row-matching-a-condition/30629948#30629948