# Hive query generating identifiers for a sequence of row matching a condition

Tags: hadoop, hive, windowing

Let's say I have the following hive table as input, let's call it `connections`:

```
userid  | timestamp   
--------|-------------
1       | 1433258019  
1       | 1433258020
2       | 1433258080
2       | 1433258083
2       | 1433258088
2       | 1433258170
[...]   | [...]
```

With the following query:

```
SELECT
    userid,
    timestamp,
    timestamp - LAG(timestamp, 1, 0) OVER w AS timediff
    CASE
      WHEN timediff > 60
      THEN 'new_session'
      ELSE 'same_session'
    END AS session_state
FROM connections
WINDOW w PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

I'm generating the following output:

```
userid  | timestamp   | timediff   | session_state
--------|-------------|------------|---------------
1       | 1433258019  | 1433258019 | new_session
1       | 1433258020  | 1          | same_session
2       | 1433258080  | 1433258080 | new_session
2       | 1433258083  | 3          | same_session
2       | 1433258088  | 5          | same_session
2       | 1433258170  | 82         | new_session
[...]   | [...]       | [...]      | [...]
```

How would I do to generate that:

```
userid  | timestamp   | timediff   | sessionid
--------|-------------|------------------------------
1       | 1433258019  | 1433258019 | user1-session-1
1       | 1433258020  | 1          | user1-session-1
2       | 1433258080  | 1433258080 | user2-session-1
2       | 1433258083  | 3          | user2-session-1
2       | 1433258088  | 5          | user2-session-1
2       | 1433258170  | 82         | user2-session-2
[...]   | [...]       | [...]      | [...]
```

Is that possible using only HQL and "famous" UDFs (I'd rather not use custom UDFs or reducer scripts) ?

Comment: Do you need "concatenation of different column values as one column output" or "some new value as sessionid".

Comment: What criteria did you use to switch from `user2-session-1` to `user2-session-2`  ?

Comment: @Ramzy having "some new value as sessionid" (I'm thinking UUID) would be great, however I could live with "concatenation of different column values as one column output" (for instance, `userid || timestamp_session_begin`)

Comment: @GoBrewers14 There was a typo in my `session_state` column values exemples above. I'm swithing sessions as soon as two connections are separated by more than 60 seconds (totally arbitrary value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.  Per your comment to @Madhu, I added the line `2 1433258172` to your example.  What you need is to increment every time `timediff > 60` is satisfied.  The easiest way to do this is to flag it and then cumulatively sum over the window.

**Query:**

```
select userid
  , timestamp
  , concat('user', userid, '-session-', s_sum) sessionid
from (
  select *
    , sum( counter ) over (partition by userid
                           order by timestamp asc
                           rows between unbounded preceding and current row) s_sum
  from (
    select *
      , case when timediff > 60 then 1 else 0 end as counter
    from (
      select userid
        , timestamp
        , timestamp - lag(timestamp, 1, 0) over (partition by userid
                                                 order by timestamp asc) timediff
      from connections ) x ) y ) z
```

**Output:**

```
1   1433258019  user1-session-1
1   1433258020  user1-session-1
2   1433258080  user2-session-1
2   1433258083  user2-session-1
2   1433258088  user2-session-1
2   1433258170  user2-session-2
2   1433258172  user2-session-2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a nice trick and it looks promising, I'll try it out ASAP. I actually found a way to solve this with a different approach, using two windows with different ORDER BY clauses and a substraction of ROW_NUMBER(). But I'll compare both queries in terms of performance (chances are yours is better) and I'll post my answer here for the sake of completeness. But unless your query is considerably slower than mine, I'll mark yours as the preffered solution (much more simple and readable).

Comment: Improves performance by 20% on ~350 million lines batches, compared to my former implementation (used somed `ROW_NUMBER()` difference magic over 2 windows : `PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY timestamp ASC` and `PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY session_state, timestamp ASC`. I didn't know about `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING [...]` till now, and this approach is much faster, feels more natural and readable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice!  No problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following
select concat_ws('-',name, city) from employee; the first parameter of concat_ws is separator. name and city are column names for employee table. See that they are of type strings. You can look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) for more

Comment: Thanks but the concatenation is not the problem. The problem is having session increment everytime there is a timediff > 60 between two connections. Which is a bit hard.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT 
  userid,
  timestamp,
  timediff,
  CONCAT(
    'user',
     userid,
     '-',
     'session-',
     CAST(timediff / 60 AS INT) + 1
  ) AS session_id
  FROM (
    SELECT   
      userid,
      timestamp,
      timestamp - LAG(timestamp, 1, timestamp) OVER w AS timediff
    FROM connections
    WINDOW w AS (
      PARTITION BY userid
      ORDER BY timestamp ASC
    )
) a;
```

OUTPUT:

```
userid  timestamp   timediff    session_state
1       1433258019  0.0         user1-session-1
1       1433258020  1.0         user1-session-1
2       1433258080  0.0         user2-session-1
2       1433258083  3.0         user2-session-1
2       1433258088  5.0         user2-session-1
2       1433258170  82.0        user2-session-2
3       1433258270  0.0         user3-session-1
```

you can try something like this if timediff is not required:

select userid,timestamp ,session_count+ concat('user',userid,'-','session-',cast(LAG(session_count-1,1,0) over w1 as string)) AS session_state
--LAG(session_count-1,1,0) over w1 AS session_count_new
FROM
(select 
     userid,
     timestamp,
     timediff,
cast (timediff/60  as int)+1 as session_count

Comment: No, that doesn't do the job. if after the row `2       1433258170  82.0  ` I get `2       1433258172  2.0` the session_state field will be `user2-session-2` for the first but will roll back to `user2-session-1` for the second. what I want is to keep the `session_id` of the preceding row if `timediff < 60`, but increment it by one (or generate a UUID) if `timediff > 60`. Currently I don't think this is possible with pure HQL however.